# Set text color of React Native WebView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a string of HTML which is to be displayed in a `WebView`. How do I set the text `color` of a React Native `WebView`?

```
<WebView source={{ html: this.props.content }}/>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100963/adding-css-styling-to-react-native-webview looks like you are in SO for a long time now hope you know how to post a question. Why are you not putting the code in the question instead of just explaining.

Comment: @Think-Twice There's just no relevant code to put here. It's just a simple WebView. If you really want it, I will do it.

Comment: People who might not be knowing what is WebView can also help you with solution by looking at the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the color of the text inside a HTML, wrap the html in a `div` tag and set the font color of the `div` in a `style`.

```
html = '<div style="color: white">' + html + '</div>';
<WebView source={{ html: html }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a small amount of content (e.g., as a test), you could insert the html string directly with formatting e.g.

```
<WebView source={{ html: "<strong>This is my Webview</strong>" }} />
```

The other way would be import your styles into your code and then export the lot as a component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {WebView} from 'react-native'
class ExternalWidget extends Component {
   render()
   {
      <WebView source={{uri:'./external/widget/index.html'}} 
         scalesPageToFit/>
   }
}
export default ExternalWidget
```

See the article [here](https://medium.com/@snehabagri.90/reactnative-webview-with-local-content-c98a09340801)

If you haven't used styles in react before, it's quite simple. Export the styles that you reference into one component, or separately as text.js/colors.js etc, and reference the component class using a variable.
E.g if var s references your [stylesheet](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet) then s.text1 will fetch the text1 class..

Good luck!

Comment: This does not answer my question. I wanted to know how to change the color of my HTML text.

Comment: @khateeb the text is within the HTML isn't it? If so, then the answer to your question is here. Read the article!

Comment: @khateeb perhaps [this](https://reactnativecode.com/render-raw-html-code/) will make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.html = this.props.data.terms_and_conditions + '<style>body{color:#464647}p,li{text-align:justify}a{color:#444}<style>'
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.flex, { marginHorizontal:15 }]}>
           <WebView
            source={{ html: this.html }}
           />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, Resolved for me.

```
<HTMLView
stylesheet={htmlStyles}
textComponentProps={{ style: {color:'red'} }}
value={content} />
```